# How can I get read receipts from LinkedIn Voyager API?

Tags: linkedin-api

I want to see if the last message has been seen by the person who I have sent the message to. I have got 20 conversation back from hitting this endpoint:
https://www.linkedin.com/voyager/api/messaging/conversations
I am using JSessions and cookies to authenticate. This is one of the conversations I got back:

```
{
            "notificationStatus": "ACTIVE",
            "read": true,
            "groupChat": false,
            "totalEventCount": 27,
            "unreadCount": 0,
            "lastActivityAt": 1613499552905,
            "firstMessageUrn": "urn:li:fs_event:(6408489350996336640,S6408489350996336640_500)",
            "backendUrn": "urn:li:messagingThread:2-MDYyMDFmMTUtMzk5NS01MTg2LWE1YWMtYzc2Y2JlYzNjYjE1XzAwMA==",
            "receipts": [
                {
                    "fromEntity": "urn:li:fs_miniProfile:ACoAACCRRgUBTOJXdRefeTMNta2hGPxadGDnNrA",
                    "seenReceipt": {
                        "seenAt": 1613498927377,
                        "eventUrn": "urn:li:fs_event:(6408489350996336640,S6767504989536559104_500)"
                    },
                    "fromParticipant": {
                        "string": "urn:li:member:546391557"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "archived": false,
            "blocked": false,
            "entityUrn": "urn:li:fs_conversation:6408489350996336640",
            "viewerCurrentParticipant": true,
            "featureTypes": [
                "REACTIONS",
                "CREATE_NEW_GROUP_CHAT"
            ],
            "withNonConnection": false,
            "muted": false,
            "events": [
                {
                    "createdAt": 1613499552888,
                    "reactionSummaries": [],
                    "dashEntityUrn": "urn:li:fsd_message:S6767507628659757056_500",
                    "quickReplyRecommendations": [],
                    "entityUrn": "urn:li:fs_event:(6408489350996336640,S6767507628659757056_500)",
                    "eventContent": {
                        "com.linkedin.voyager.messaging.event.MessageEvent": {
                            "messageBodyRenderFormat": "DEFAULT",
                            "body": "",
                            "attributedBody": {
                                "text": "some more text"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "subtype": "MEMBER_TO_MEMBER",
                    "from": {
                        "com.linkedin.voyager.messaging.MessagingMember": {
                            "miniProfile": {
                                "memorialized": false,
                                "firstName": "Sepideh",
                                "lastName": "Falah",
                                "occupation": "Software Engineer at SocialCycle",
                                "objectUrn": "urn:li:member:192299229",
                                "entityUrn": "urn:li:fs_miniProfile:ACoAAAt2QN0ByntmuEeEZB7874UZ84rt5wR4sL4",
                                "publicIdentifier": "sepideh-falah-33949854",
                                "picture": {
                                    "com.linkedin.common.VectorImage": {
                                        "artifacts": [
                                            {
                                                "width": 100,
                                                "fileIdentifyingUrlPathSegment": "100_100/0/1516745437487?e=1619049600&v=beta&t=WXbHMyBCelbHjHoWSEVbi4TydR7qMeehH15FWpJYIao",
                                                "expiresAt": 1619049600000,
                                                "height": 100
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "width": 200,
                                                "fileIdentifyingUrlPathSegment": "200_200/0/1516745437487?e=1619049600&v=beta&t=66x3s8Hw5BvedUqu1RZ2TNazf2o0y9amUAJbKIx2nLI",
                                                "expiresAt": 1619049600000,
                                                "height": 200
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "width": 400,
                                                "fileIdentifyingUrlPathSegment": "400_400/0/1516745437487?e=1619049600&v=beta&t=MM1mHaQP6KTfNgJRIEuPQ0_2l76eA-DQbt0v4SiVs-0",
                                                "expiresAt": 1619049600000,
                                                "height": 400
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "width": 800,
                                                "fileIdentifyingUrlPathSegment": "800_800/0/1516745437487?e=1619049600&v=beta&t=YW7bUQO8Vpext2at7SW5FQhuot81Xk1HCnbJ_2jdjAI",
                                                "expiresAt": 1619049600000,
                                                "height": 800
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "rootUrl": "https://media-exp1.licdn.com/dms/image/C5103AQEJ4t5ijWZ8Xg/profile-displayphoto-shrink_"
                                    }
                                },
                                "trackingId": "ZJXqw5fwRdCZPQpx0d1yhw=="
                            },
                            "entityUrn": "urn:li:fs_messagingMember:(6408489350996336640,ACoAAAt2QN0ByntmuEeEZB7874UZ84rt5wR4sL4)",
                            "nameInitials": "SF"
                        }
                    },
                    "previousEventInConversation": "urn:li:fs_event:(6408489350996336640,S6767504989536559104_500)",
                    "originToken": "07ea6a5d-7450-4a22-b5f4-ceb599e16ab4",
                    "backendUrn": "urn:li:messagingMessage:2-MTYxMzQ5OTU1MjY4NGI3NTYwOS0wMDEmMDYyMDFmMTUtMzk5NS01MTg2LWE1YWMtYzc2Y2JlYzNjYjE1XzAwMA=="
                }
            ],
            "participants": [
                {
                    "com.linkedin.voyager.messaging.MessagingMember": {
                        "miniProfile": {
                            "memorialized": false,
                            "firstName": "Trevor",
                            "lastName": "Johnson",
                            "occupation": "Software Developer at Axway",
                            "objectUrn": "urn:li:member:546391557",
                            "entityUrn": "urn:li:fs_miniProfile:ACoAACCRRgUBTOJXdRefeTMNta2hGPxadGDnNrA",
                            "publicIdentifier": "johnson-trevor",
                            "picture": {
                                "com.linkedin.common.VectorImage": {
                                    "artifacts": [
                                        {
                                            "width": 100,
                                            "fileIdentifyingUrlPathSegment": "100_100/0/1524789372523?e=1619049600&v=beta&t=9ystm3UQKcVGh6sc5OYOkc8NjA0KzGwo9XRrNOYZOJo",
                                            "expiresAt": 1619049600000,
                                            "height": 100
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "width": 200,
                                            "fileIdentifyingUrlPathSegment": "200_200/0/1524789372523?e=1619049600&v=beta&t=nIqjHKqUN9N2_cXGfG4iDcfxjJkC7DGGDKD_yawbm40",
                                            "expiresAt": 1619049600000,
                                            "height": 200
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "width": 400,
                                            "fileIdentifyingUrlPathSegment": "400_400/0/1524789372523?e=1619049600&v=beta&t=l1fwjGmn-cxqwc5S-1IF5Y1HWg99akHkUQt3caorZPA",
                                            "expiresAt": 1619049600000,
                                            "height": 400
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "width": 800,
                                            "fileIdentifyingUrlPathSegment": "800_800/0/1524789372523?e=1619049600&v=beta&t=pj8u5JMqmLVuEFKNSbPT8fg7UfXTDE82wsJ6Uc6Urio",
                                            "expiresAt": 1619049600000,
                                            "height": 800
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "rootUrl": "https://media-exp1.licdn.com/dms/image/C5603AQGDs9cCCR0HSw/profile-displayphoto-shrink_"
                                }
                            },
                            "trackingId": "Yvzot8irQWmbRWKMpIRKKg=="
                        },
                        "entityUrn": "urn:li:fs_messagingMember:(6408489350996336640,ACoAACCRRgUBTOJXdRefeTMNta2hGPxadGDnNrA)",
                        "nameInitials": "TJ"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Append `conversationUrn` to the link you are using.

I see that `"entityUrn": "urn:li:fs_conversation:6408489350996336640"`

In that case URL will be:
`https://www.linkedin.com/voyager/api/messaging/conversations/6408489350996336640/events`

It will return you the list of messages (events) from 1 specified above conversation with details of every message.

BTW, it's interesting that in your case `conversationUrn` is `6408489350996336640`. Usually it looks like `2-MGQxMGNkMTctNGIxOS00N2RhLTgyMmUtNDE0MzAyYjI1ODRkXzAxMg==`